# Signalr 2 Autofac calling Hub two to three times in a request

Tags: c#, signalr, autofac

You'll have to excuse the strange title but after several hours of looking at the same issue, it's the best I could come up with!

I initially had signalr embedded with my MVC project but moved it out into an self-hosted OWIN application.

When ever a hub is called upon, on the initial load it will load the hub twice and subsequent calls it will load it three times.

Here is my hub, and I followed the documentation to the tee:

```
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;
    private ITestService _testService;

    public TestHub(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        _scope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope();
        _testService = _scope.Resolve<ITestService>();
    }

    public void SignalRTest()
    {
        var types = _testService.SomeMethod();
        Clients.Caller.populateSignalRTest(types);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && _scope != null)
        {
            _scope.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose (disposing);
    }
}
```

Here is the OWIN configuration:

```
var listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties[typeof(HttpListener).FullName];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// ... Other modules being imported ...
builder.RegisterModule<NLogModule>();
builder.RegisterType<TestService> ().As<ITestService> ();
builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var config = new HubConfiguration();
var container = builder.Build();
config.Resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
appBuilder.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
appBuilder.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);
```

Autofac has to resolve all dependencies before running any methods - the application calls upon mulitple Hubs and this takes a long time to resolve.

Here are the versions I am using:

```
SignalR 2.1.2 (Also tried 2.2.0)
AutoFac 3.5.2
```

Has anyone come across this or know why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague did a bit of debugging whilst I raged and did something else and discovered it was one of the services rather than AutoFac or signalR.  We have an Index and the constructor method of the service was verifying the index was valid.  Remove it and it was fine.